# How to construct a set out of list items in python?

Tags: python, list, set

I have a `list` of filenames in python and I would want to construct a `set` out of all the filenames.

```
filelist=[]
for filename in filelist:
    set(filename)
```

This does not seem to work. How can do this?

Answer (score 452, accepted):

If you have a list of hashable objects (filenames would probably be strings, so they should count):

```
lst = ['foo.py', 'bar.py', 'baz.py', 'qux.py', Ellipsis]
```

you can construct the set directly:

```
s = set(lst)
```

In fact, `set` will work this way with *any iterable object!*  (Isn't duck typing great?)

---

If you want to do it iteratively:

```
s = set()
for item in iterable:
    s.add(item)
```

But there's rarely a need to do it this way.  I only mention it because the `set.add` method is quite useful.

Comment: I am using 2.7 and this does not seem to work.  What's going on here?
    Python 2.7.13 (default, Jul 24 2017, 14:22:59) 
    [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)] on darwin
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> x = [1,2,3]
    >>> set(x)
   set([1, 2, 3])
>>>

Comment: @user1902291-- It looks like it worked, you just neek to keep track of the resulting set:  `y = set(x)`

Comment: Also note that adding items in the set from a list can prove to be very useful when you want to filter out duplicates from the list.

Comment: How about `s = {'foo.py', 'bar.py', 'baz.py', 'qux.py', Ellipsis}`?

Comment: Yes, that works -- though it isn't actually constructing a set out of a list of items as OP was requesting :).  That's making a set literal.

Answer (score 27):

The most direct solution is this:

```
s = set(filelist)
```

The issue in your original code is that the values weren't being assigned to the *set*.  Here's the fixed-up version of your code:

```
s = set()
for filename in filelist:
    s.add(filename)
print(s)
```

Answer (score 22):

You can do

```
my_set = set(my_list)
```

or, in Python 3,

```
my_set = {*my_list}
```

to create a set from a list. Conversely, you can also do

```
my_list = list(my_set)
```

or, in Python 3,

```
my_list = [*my_set]
```

to create a list from a set.

Just note that the order of the elements in a list is generally lost when converting the list to a set since a set is inherently unordered. (One exception in CPython, though, seems to be if the list consists only of non-negative integers, but I assume this is a consequence of the implementation of sets in CPython and that this behavior can vary between different Python implementations.)

Answer (score 6):

Here is another solution:

```
>>>list1=["C:\\","D:\\","E:\\","C:\\"]
>>>set1=set(list1)
>>>set1
set(['E:\\', 'D:\\', 'C:\\'])
```

In this code I have used the set method in order to turn it into a set and then it removed all duplicate values from the list

Answer (score 2):

You can also use list comprehension to create set.

```
s = {i for i in range(5)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply put the line:

```
new_list = set(your_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

One general way to construct set in iterative way like this:

```
aset = {e for e in alist}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers are correct but if you want to preserve the order of your list you'll need to proceed as follow

```
list(dict.fromkeys(your_list))
```