# Passing set, list and Dictionary as argument to Python function

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

Please check my code below and make necessary corrections. It is giving me an error message.

The assignment is shown below.

> Create a function `manipulate_data` that does the following
>
> 1. Accepts as the first parameter a `string` specifying the data structure to be used `list`, `set` or `dictionary`
> 2. Accepts as the second parameter the data to be manipulated based on the data structure specified e.g `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25]` for a `list` data structure
> 3. Based off the first parameter
>
>    - return the reverse of a list or
>    - add items `"ANDELA"`, `"TIA"` and `"AFRICA"` to the set and return the resulting set
>    - return the keys of a dictionary.

My solution code is below:

```py
def manipulate_data(argument1, argument2):
   if argument1 == "list":
     argument2.reverse()
return argument2

if argument1 == "set":
   argument2.add("ANDELA")
   argument2.add("TIA")
   argument2.add("AFRICA")
return argument2

if argument1 == "dictionary":
   argument2.keys()
return argument2
```

I don't know if I am making sense at all. The error messages received are:

```
Total Specs: 3 Total Failures: 2

test_manipulate_dictionary
Failure in line 23, in test_manipulate_dictionary self.assertEqual(result, ["grapes", "mangoes", "apples", "oranges"], msg = "Dictionary not manipulated correctly") AssertionError: Dictionary not manipulated correctly
```

and

```
test_manipulate_set
    Failure in line 19, in test_manipulate_set self.assertEqual(result, {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "ANDELA", "TIA", "AFRICA"}, msg = "Set not manipulated correctly") AssertionError: Set not manipulated correctly
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801231/someone-please-take-a-look-at-my-python-syntax).

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track but i think you have passed arguments incorrectly to your function in case of `dict` and `set` because by default `{}` signifies a dictionary

Something like this:

```
def manipulate_data(argument1, argument2):
    if argument1 == "list":
        argument2.reverse()
        return argument2

    if argument1 == "set":
        argument2.update(["ANDELA", "TIA", "AFRICA"])
        return argument2

    if argument1 == "dictionary":
        return argument2.keys()

print(manipulate_data('list', [1,2,3,4,5,6]), manipulate_data('set', {1,2,3,4,5,6}), manipulate_data('dictionary', {1:2,3:4,5:6}), sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
$ python3 a.py 
[6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
{'ANDELA', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 'TIA', 'AFRICA'}
dict_keys([1, 3, 5])
$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def manipulate_data(argument1, argument2):
    if argument1 == "list":
        if isinstance(argument2, list):
            argument2.reverse()
            return argument2

    if argument1 == "set":
        if isinstance(argument2, set):
            argument2.add("ANDELA")
            argument2.add("TIA")
            argument2.add("AFRICA")
            return argument2

    if argument1 == "dictionary":
        if isinstance(argument2, dict):
            return argument2.keys()

l = [1,2,3]
d = {'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3 }
s = set()
s.add(1)
s.add(2)
s.add(3)

print manipulate_data("list", l)
print manipulate_data("dictionary", d)
print manipulate_data("set", s)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would explain in your answer what was wrong with the OP's code and what you changed to solve it.

Comment: I am already doing his/her homework for him/her, mate.  And frankly, the code is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: If the code is self-explanatory, it should be easy to explain.  If you don't think the question is suitable to be answered correctly, flag it to be closed.  An answer has some responsibility with it.

Comment: Thanks marienbad. Your code has answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
def manipulate_data(arg1, arg2):
    if arg1 == "list":
        arg2.reverse()
        return arg2,type(arg2)

    #http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768757/how-to-construct-a-set-out-of-list-items
    if arg1 == "set":
        myset=set(arg2)
        myset.add("ANDELA")
        myset.add("TIA")
        myset.add("AFRICA")
        return myset,type(myset)

    if arg1 == "dictionary":
        mydict={}
        for l in arg2:
            mydict[l]=l
        return mydict.keys(),type(mydict)


print manipulate_data("list",[1, 4, 9, 16, 25])
print manipulate_data("set",[1, 4, 9, 16, 25])
print manipulate_data("dictionary",[1, 4, 9, 16, 25])
```

Output:

```
([25, 16, 9, 4, 1], <type 'list'>)
(set([1, 4, 9, 'AFRICA', 16, 25, 'TIA', 'ANDELA']), <type 'set'>)
([16, 1, 4, 25, 9], <type 'dict'>)
```