# Create a set from a series in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series, kaggle

I have a dataframe extracted from Kaggle's San Fransico Salaries: https://www.kaggle.com/kaggle/sf-salaries
and I wish to create a set of the values of a column, for instance 'Status'.

This is what I have tried but it brings a list of all the records instead of the set (sf is how I name the data frame).

```
a=set(sf['Status'])
print a
```

According to this webpage, this should work.
[How to construct a set out of list items in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768757/how-to-construct-a-set-out-of-list-items)

Comment: Why do you tsay `a` is a list?

Comment: perhaps I used the term incorrectly, i refer that it gives me all the values from the column without caring if it is pure nans for instance

Answer (score 115, accepted):

If you only need to get list of unique values, you can just use `unique` method.
If you want to have Python's set, then do `set(some_series)`

```
In [1]: s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 4])

In [2]: s.unique()
Out[2]: array([1, 2, 3, 4])

In [3]: set(s)
Out[3]: {1, 2, 3, 4}
```

However, if you have DataFrame, just select series out of it ( `some_data_frame['<col_name>']` ).

Answer (score 43):

With large size `series` with duplicates the `set(some_series)` execution-time will evolve exponentially with `series` size.

Better practice would be to `set(some_series.unique())`.

A simple exemple showing x16 execution time.[image]

Comment: Could anyone explain why the execution time evolves exponentially without using unique?

Comment: some_series.unique() gives every unique item in the series = basically a set. Creating a set from a set is fast because you have no duplicates --> less items to work on --> less work to do --> fast. Pandas is mostly C under the hood, maybe set() is not that optimized compared to .unique()?
Question is: Does this speedup still holds up if your series is already unique --> you don't throw anything out when using .unique()?

Comment: Also dont think it would evolve exponentially, what would be the reason?

Comment: I think he must have meant quadratically.