# Create a set in Python and append the values from another list to it

Tags: python-3.x

I have list 2 which has all the items fron list 1 and x :

```
 import random
 for x in range(10):
 print(random.randint(1,101))

 list1 = ''
 list.append(x)
 list2 = list1
```

How can I create a set and add all the items from list 2 into a set? All the code up to this point is what I  have been told to do and I have no idea how to create a set and append items to it.

Comment: You can make a set from any iterable by doing `set(list2)`. (Note that this creates a new `set` object, it doesn't turn `list2` into a `set`)  The code you posted here has a lot of problems, not the least of which is that you don't define any lists in it.

Comment: soz yh code wouldnt post in original form idk y so i edited it a bit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to construct a set out of list items in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768757/how-to-construct-a-set-out-of-list-items-in-python)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this. I convert list to set in the end.

```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


    import random
    list1 = []

    for x in range(10):
        number = random.randint(1,101)
        list1.append(number)


    list2 = list1
    new_set = set(list2)
    print (new_set)
```