# convert python list into dictionary with key only , no value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of room names in python, however I need it to be a dictionary, simply in the form `{"room1", "room2", "room3"}`

Currently, my code can take the list and turn to a dictionary with both values and keys, i.e. `{"room1":0, "room2":1, "room3": 2}` etc.

my code is as follows:

```
rooms = ["G5a", "G5b", "G11"]
roomdict = dict(zip(rooms,range(len(rooms))))

print(roomdict)
```

But, this is not the format I need my dictionary to be in - thanks for your help in advanace :)

Comment: You mean a `set`?

Comment: Thats not a `dict` behaviour

Comment: There is no such thing as a dictionary with no values. `{a, b, c}` is a set. Which is a different type of structure. You could perhaps use a dictionary where all values are just set to None?

Comment: yeah sure - not sure what its called - just need it to be name = {"room1", "room2", "room3"} etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to construct a set out of list items in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768757/how-to-construct-a-set-out-of-list-items-in-python)

Comment: Although of course the keys of a dictionary are a set, a Python dictionary's keys also maintain their insertion order.  So in situations where you want to maintain the order of the keys, this is the right question to ask.

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of "How to construct a set ...", because constructing a dictionary with just keys is a distinct and worthwhile goal, as I argued in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is a [set](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set):

A set is an unordered collection of items. Every element is unique (no duplicates) and must be immutable (which cannot be changed).

```
rooms = ["G5a", "G5b", "G11"]
print(set(rooms))
```

OUTPUT:

```
{'G5b', 'G5a', 'G11'}
```

Answer (score 2):

On the odd chance that your really need a dict with keys and empty values:

```
mydict = {"room1" : None, "room2": None, "room3" : None}
```

You could use the `dict.fromkeys()` method:

```
rooms = ["G5a", "G5b", "G11"]
roomdict = dict.fromkeys(rooms, None)

print(roomdict)
```

Output:

```
{'G5b': None, 'G11': None, 'G5a': None}
```