# I need the number of elements that appears only once

Tags: python, list

I need the element that appears only occur once. (python)

For example the result for

```
mylist = ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']
```

would be

```
2
```

Comment: I think the result should be 3 for that example?

Comment: Why 2? shouldn't that by 3?

Comment: @brunns - the question isn't really clear. They want to know the count of element that only occur once -> `b` and `c`

Comment: Yeah - I think @blhsing's answer gives them what they want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` to count the number of occurrences of each distinct item, and retain only those with a count of 1 with a generator expression:

```
from collections import Counter
sum(1 for c in Counter(mylist).values() if c == 1)
```

This returns: `2`

Comment: golfing `sum(c==1 for k, c in Counter(mylist).items())`

Comment: I knew about that approach but it is less efficient because `sum` would then have to iterate through more numbers. Filtering first makes `sum` faster. See demo: https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/19uT

Comment: golfing just faster ... to type. You can anonymize the key: `sum(1 for c in Counter(mylist).values() if c == 1)`

Comment: Ah indeed I forgot that keys are not needed here. Updated as suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This situation looks like a pure Set structure.
If I were you I would turn the array to set and check the size of it.

You can check examples how to do it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768757/how-to-construct-a-set-out-of-list-items-in-python)

Comment: That would output 3 for `['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']`. OP wants to count the number of elements which only occur once, so `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to iterate through the list and check to see how many times each element occurs in the list. If it occurs more than once, you don't want it but if it occurs only once, you increase your counter by 1.

```
count = 0

for letter in mylist:
  if mylist.count(letter) == 1:
    count += 1

print (count)
```

Comment: You're going to count 'a' four times but it's going to work. I prefer the Counter approach, though.

Comment: @EricDarchis How do you think the counter does it? If we're talking complexity-wise I think they're the same. If we're talking simplicity and readibility, I prefer this one. It's just simple.

Comment: Please explain your answer. Do not give code-only answers.

Comment: @AdamZahran no, this is quadratic time, whereas a `Counter` based approach is linear time

Comment: The Counter is a special dictionary. So you browse the array only once and increment the counters in the dict as you go. As @juanpa.arrivillaga states, you're browsing the array len(mylist)*len(mylist) times instead of len(mylist)+len(unique items). The drawback of the counter is that it uses more memory. But if that's of any matter, the n² complexity is going to be much worse anyway.

Answer (score -1):

This should work for you:

```
len(set(mylist))
```

It does require your values to be hashable.

Comment: That would output 3 for `['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']`. OP wants to count the number of elements which only occur once, so `b` and `c`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I wouldn't describe that as unique elements, but I see what they are getting at.

Comment: You mean `set()`?