# how to seperate grouped items in sqlite3 through python

Tags: python, sqlite, search

iv started using database for my program instead of .txt files and i would like to make a search function

iv got the basics of the search function ( dropdown menu with all the possible choices) but with most of the items theres multiple items in 1 column/row for example

### column "food_name" " Ingredients" " recipe"

```
           potato casserole    potato,cheese,ect
```

but in my search function potato,cheese is 1 item how can i seprate it??

and my second question obviously theres going to be foods with similier ingredients how can i stop it from showing multiples of the same ingredient and still bring up the result of all the foods with the same ingredient??

[option 1 has cheese selected
option 2 has potato and cheese selected ( but i want it to be seprated)
option 3 at the top it shows cheese and at the buttom it shows cheese (from 2 differnt foods) and i want to only have 1 instance of that ingredient but return all the foods with that ingredient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1EZ9b.png)

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import Combobox
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect("Food.db")
c = con.cursor()

c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Order")
order = c.fetchall()
c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Stove")
stove = c.fetchall()
c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Oven")
oven = c.fetchall()
c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Cold")
cold = c.fetchall()
c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Simple")
simple = c.fetchall()
con.commit()

dinner_order = order
dinner_stove = stove
dinner_oven = oven
dinner_cold = cold
dinner_simple = simple

ws = Tk()
ws.title("Python Guides")
ws.geometry("200x200")



item_names = dinner_order + dinner_stove + dinner_oven + dinner_simple + dinner_cold

combo = Combobox(ws, state='readonly')
combo['values'] = item_names
combo.pack()

combo = Combobox(ws, state='readonly')
combo['values'] = item_names
combo.pack()

combo = Combobox(ws, state='readonly')
combo['values'] = item_names
combo.pack()

combo = Combobox(ws, state='readonly')
combo['values'] = item_names
combo.pack()

button = Button(ws, text="search", )#command=search_items)
button.pack()

ws.mainloop()
```

Comment: It's difficult to provide any feedback with the information that you provide. Add a minimal code, and example data

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to `split` the result on `,`, for example if the query returns `"potato,cheese,ect"` you would do:

```py
"potato,cheese,ect".split(",")
```

Something like this:

```py
>>> c.execute("SELECT Ingredients FROM Dinner_Simple WHERE food_name ='potato casserole'")
>>> ingredients = c.fetchall()
>>> print(ingredients)
"potato,cheese,ect"
>>> ingredients = ingredients.split(",")
>>> print(ingredients)
["potato", "cheese", "ect"]
```

Comment: how do i .split(",") inside the database? ( i used DB browser(SQlite) to add all the infomation into the database)

Comment: @ZFV6, what I meant was when you executed your SQL query and retrieved your data from your database, then you can do a simple `split` to convert that string to a list.

Comment: do i need to use the "where" code? because every food will have multiple ingredients and going through 40-50 differnt foods for each ingredient kinda beats the point of the database ( plus the user has the option to add more foods/ingredients/recipes and those wont apear in the search dropbox)

and my other question is:
is it possible to remove duplicates of the same ingredient?

Comment: i have to convert it into string first before i can split it and then the option with potato,cheese becomes ('potato and \n\rcheese how can i remove the symbols?

Comment: no you don't need to use `where`, that was just an example.
to remove duplicates from a list you can convert it to a `set`, here is more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15768757/how-to-construct-a-set-out-of-list-items-in-python
the best way to remove the character such as `\n` or `\r` is using regex, or you can also use `replace` method on your string